# Как получить несколько вариантов массива для обработки в цикле (php, html)?

Tags: php, html, mysql, массивы, foreach

Есть код, примерно такой:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Артикул 1:
             <input type="text" value="" name="skus[][name]"><br>
             <input type="text" value="" name="skus[][code]"><br>
    Артикул 2:
             <input type="text" value="" name="skus[][name]"><br>
             <input type="text" value="" name="skus[][code]"><br>
    Артикул 3 и так далее:
          <button type="submit" name="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Нужно получить из этой формы значения в PHP для обработки в цикле с последующим добавлением в базу данных, чтобы результат был примерно таким:

```
skus 1 = name, code
skus 2 = name, code
skus 3 = name, code
```

Как получить данные именно всех массивов skus со значениями, чтобы в цикле получилось примерно так:

```
foreach ($_POST['skus'] as $key => $sku) {
      $sku_name = $sku['name'];
      $sku_code = $sku['code'];
      $values[] = '("'.$sku_name.'", "'.$sku_code.'")';
    }
    $sql = 'insert into bla bla values'.$values';
```

А то на данный момент получается только последний массив, либо все значения получаются в одном массиве skus, а нужно принимать все массивы skus, каждый уникальный со своими значениями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

следует использовать индекс в именах инпутов.

```
<input name="sku[0][name]"/>
<input name="sku[0][code]"/>
<input name="sku[1][name]"/>
<input name="sku[1][code]"/>
```

тогда в `$_POST` получите нормальный массив

```
[
   ['name' => ..., 'code' => ....],
   ['name' => ..., 'code' => ....],
]
```

далее можно формировать SQL запрос на вставку. Однако, метод подстановки, который вы используете - не безопасен. Следует параметризовать запрос и использовать подготовленные выражения для избежания SQL инъекций.

Comment: Спасибо, так я пробовал, работает, да, но у меня проблема в том, что артикулы добавляются динамически по нажатию кнопки, и предугадать сколько их будет - неизвестно, а как присваивать им индекс динамически - не знаю. То есть, нажал кнопку "добавить артикул", появились ещё 2 поля sku[][name] и sku[][code] и так до бесконечности. Может у вас есть вариант решения?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал, как написал в ответе teran + добавил динамическое добавление индекса по нажатию кнопки.

Что-то вроде этого:

```
<script>
var counter = 1;

$('.sku-add').click(function(e) {
    counter++;
    $('.sku').append('<input name="sku['+ counter +'][name]"/><input name="sku['+ counter +'][code]"/>');
}
</script>
```

А дальше уже обработка foreach и добавление в базу.

Comment: убедитесь, что сервер корректно воспринимает массив с пропусками в индексации. добавьте 3 блока, удалите средний, получите индексы 0 и 2. проверьте при отправке что 2 тоже придет. не помню кто из серверов, но отсекает после пропусков и для этого есть решение в виде какого-то хидден поля с каким-то именем, но я никак вспомнить не могу как оно зовется. а-ля чтобы при отправке перенумерованы они стали по порядку